# Bulk insert mapped array using pymongo fails due to BulkWriteError

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I am trying to bulk insert documents in MongoDB using python library `pymongo`.

```
import pymongo
def tryManyInsert():
    p = {'x' : 1, 'y' : True, 'z': None}
    mongoColl = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)['test']['multiIn']
    mongoColl.insert_many([p for i in range(10)])
tryManyInsert()
```

But I keep failing due to `BulkWriteError`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/prog_path/testMongoCon.py", line 9, in <module>
    tryManyInsert();
    File "/prog_path/testMongoCon.py", line 7, in tryManyInsert
mongoColl.insert_many([p for i in range(10)])
    File "/myenv_path/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 724, in insert_many
blk.execute(self.write_concern.document)
    File "/myenv_path/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/bulk.py", line 493, in execute
return self.execute_command(sock_info, generator, write_concern)
    File "/myenv_path/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/bulk.py", line 331, in execute_command
raise BulkWriteError(full_result)
    pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred
```

I am trying to insert only 10 docs sequentially without `_id` so conditions in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073956/pymongo-errors-bulkwriteerror-batch-op-errors-occurred-mongodb-3-4-2-pymongo) / [discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/xaddTC01FCk/LMTCQEarAgAJ) doesn't apply here. Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422024/how-to-insert-data-into-the-mongodb-database-in-bulk-using-python) has no answer.

I have tried `pymongo 3.4` and `pymongo 3.5.1`, both give the same error. I am on `python3.6`, `mongodb 3.2.10`. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is still referring to `p` as being the same thing for each array member. You want a [`copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) of `p` for each array member:

```
import pymongo
from copy import copy
def tryManyInsert():
    p = {'x' : 1, 'y' : True, 'z': None}
    mongoColl = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)['test']['multiIn']
    mongoColl.insert_many([copy(p) for i in range(10)])
tryManyInsert()
```

Or even simply:

```
    mongoColl.insert_many([{ 'x': 1, 'y': True, 'z': None } for i in range(10)])
```

Unless you do that the `_id` only gets assigned **once** and you are simply repeating "the same document" with the same `_id` in the argument to `insert_many()`. Hence the error for a duplicate key.

As a quick demonstration:

```
from bson import ObjectId

p = { 'a': 1 }

def addId(obj):
  obj['_id'] = ObjectId()
  return obj

docs = map(addId,[p for i in range(2)])
print docs
```

Gives you:

```
[
  {'a': 1, '_id': ObjectId('59fbc4a16cb6b30bdb3de0fd')}, 
  {'a': 1, '_id': ObjectId('59fbc4a16cb6b30bdb3de0fd')}
]
```

Or more succinctly:

```
p = { 'a': 1 }

def addKey(x):
  x[0]['b'] = x[1]
  return x[0]

docs = map(addKey,[[p,i] for i,p in enumerate([p for i in range(3)])])
print docs
```

Gives:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
```

Which clearly demonstrates the index value passed overwriting the same value which was passed in.

But using [`copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) to take a copy of the value:

```
from bson import ObjectId

p = { 'a': 1 }

def addId(obj):
  obj['_id'] = ObjectId()
  return obj

docs = map(addId,[copy(p) for i in range(2)])
print docs
```

Gives you:

```
[
  {'a': 1, '_id': ObjectId('59fbc5466cb6b30be4d0fc00')},
  {'a': 1, '_id': ObjectId('59fbc5466cb6b30be4d0fc01')}
]
```

Or our base demonstration:

```
p = { 'a': 1 }

def addKey(x):
  x[0]['b'] = x[1]
  return x[0]

docs = map(addKey,[[p,i] for i,p in enumerate([copy(p) for i in range(3)])])
print docs
```

Returns:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 0}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
```

So this is basically how python works. If you don't actually deliberately assign to a new value, then all you are doing is returning the same referenced value and simply updating each referenced value in the loop, rather than producing a "new one".

Comment: Yes, thank you for the explanation. I should have read the [docs](https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.5.1/tutorial.html) more carefully which stated `When a document is inserted a special key, "_id", is automatically added if the document doesn’t already contain an "_id" key.`

Comment: @parthasarathy Well that is part of it, however the real point here is how python handles object assignment. So the key difference here is a "copy" as opposed to the "same reference" being mapped into the array.